why on Android 13 Splash Screen Icon is not showing at all (On Cold Start)
I am running my app on Android 13, splash screen is being shown without icon
Implemented according to off docs (https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/launch/splash-screen)
On android 9 icon is shown ok.
I tried to use png/webp icons, then wrapped them into layer-list with fixed size, after that tried svg icon, after tried adaptive icon also, nothing works.
<style name="Theme.App.Starting" parent="Theme.SplashScreen">
        <item name="windowSplashScreenBackground">@color/splash_screen_background_color</item>
        <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@drawable/splash_screen_icon</item>
        <item name="postSplashScreenTheme">@style/Theme.App.Starting.Fallback</item>
        <item name="splashScreenIconSize">100dp</item>
        <item name="android:windowSplashScreenBehavior" tools:targetApi="33">icon_preferred</item>
    </style>

